# Script encrypts, but still saves the plaintext instead of the ciphertext

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, file-io, caesar-cipher

I have an issue with my current program where it is supposed to take a user input, encrypt it by allowing you to choose how much you want to shift by, then save to a file. For unknown reasons my program seems to be capable of saving the file however it is completely missing out the encryption. Any help with be much appreciated.

```
text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 1234567890-=!Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â£%^&*"

def main():
    #if they want to save the file after the encrypting if statement
    ans = input("Would you like to save to a file of read a file, press w or r").lower()

    if ans == "w":
        text = input("What is your text you want to enter").lower()

        caeser(text)
        save_file()

    elif ans == "r":
        text = input("What is your file name you want to enter").lower()
        caeser(text)

# organise loop & function
def caeser(text):
    shift = int(input("How much would you like to shift?: "))
    shifted_list = []
    for letter in text:
        character_lower = letter.lower()
        ASCII = ord(character_lower)
        shift = shift % 26
        shifted_letter = ASCII + shift
        shifted_char = chr(shifted_letter)
        shift_loop = shifted_letter - 26
        shift_loop_char = chr(shift_loop)
        if shifted_letter >= 97 and shifted_letter <= 122:
            shifted_list.append(shifted_char)
            text = ''.join(shifted_list)
        elif shift_loop >= 97 and shift_loop <= 122:
            shifted_list.append(shift_loop_char)
            text = ''.join(shifted_list)
        else:
            shifted_list.append(character_lower)
            text = ''.join(shifted_list)
        encrypted = text
    return encrypted

# save file shouldnt return text
def save_file(text):
    name = input("Enter filename")
    file = open(name, "w")
    file.write(text)
    file.close()

#load file shouldnt recieve a parameter  
# error protection needs to be added  
def load_file(text):
    name = input("Please enter a file name")
    file = open(name, "r")
    text = file.read()
    file.close()
    return text
```

Comment: `encrypted = text` should not be in the `for` loop - you are overwriting it for each letter. Dedent it.

Answer (score 1):

Python strings are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). You need to change this:

```
# returns encrypted text and does nothing with it
caeser(text)
# saves 'text' from module-level namespace, since you send nothing
save_file()
```

To this:

```
# send encrypted text returned by 'caesar(text)' to save_file
save_file(caeser(text))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    caeser(text)
    save_file()
```

The return value is not assign to any variable, so you just throw way the result.

```
    text = caeser(text)
```

would solve that.

Comment: OP doesn't have a variable named `new_char`. His problem, in addition to what you've noted, is that `encrypted = text` is in the wrong place (or should be `encrypted += text` I didn't work out his algo).

Comment: I know (knew ?) he doesn't have newchar... I was just showing how to concatenate a char + string. Anyway, that part of the answer was incorrect anyway - he did return a string (I hadn't noticed the join), so I removed that part of the answer.